# How to recover a USB stick after Ubuntu installation?

Tags: 12.04, usb, xubuntu, live-usb

I have created a liveUSB-stick with Xubuntu 12.04 on it. I installed Xubuntu from it on a MacBook Air. If I now plug in the usb stick, it is not recognized anymore. How can I make it recognized and format it in order to use it again as a normal storage USB stick?

Comment: Plug it in and format it.

Comment: Well, that was my idea. But I don't see the USB stick anywhere in the file system, it is not mounted in /media. And: How can I format it?

Comment: If you are using Linux, try the command "dmesg". It will show you whether the device has been detected or not.

Comment: For how to format using the command line, check this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/9499/how-do-you-format-a-usb-stick-in-ubuntu-server

Comment: okay, I saw with `dmesg` that /dev/sdc has 2 GB, so I guess that's my USB stick. I then tried `sudo mkfs -t vfat  /dev/sdc` and obtained: "Device partition expected, not making filesystem on entire device '/dev/sdc' (use -I to override)". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In the dmesg, did you see "sdc1" along with sdc? If yes, then sdc1 is what you should format as sdc is the device itself and sdc1 is the partition on it.

Comment: Yes, I saw sdc1 as well. I used that, so mkfs worked. But afterwards, the USB stick was still not visible. I then used fdisk as suggested by vicd below, that worked

Answer (score 8, accepted):

here's some simple instructions just for your reference.

A. First we need to delete the old partitions that remain on the USB key.

```
Open a terminal and type sudo su
Type fdisk -l and note your USB drive letter.
Type fdisk /dev/sdx (replacing x with your drive letter)
Type d to proceed to delete a partition
Type 1 to select the 1st partition and press enter
Type d to proceed to delete another partition (fdisk should automatically select the second partition)
```

B. Next we need to create the new partition.

```
Type n to make a new partition
Type p to make this partition primary and press enter
Type 1 to make this the first partition and then press enter
Press enter to accept the default first cylinder
Press enter again to accept the default last cylinder
Type w to write the new partition information to the USB key
Type umount /dev/sdx1 (replacing x with your drive letter)
```

C. The last step is to create the fat filesystem.

```
Type mkfs.vfat -F 32 /dev/sdx1 (replacing x with your USB key drive letter)
```

That's it, you should now have a restored USB key with a single fat 32 partition that can be read from any computer.

Comment: Thanks vicd for the details, exactly what I was looking for. I indeed now see the USB stick again :-) It has the strange name D4C4-DD6D. How (or where) could I have specified a normal name like "USB"?

Comment: Glad to hear you've solved this issue. To label your usb stick, feel free to use **-n** option, if you want to specify a name like "USB", try this command `mkfs.vfat -F 32 -n USB /dev/sdx1`

Comment: In addtion, you can get this done easily by using "Gparted Partion Editor"(default installed in ubuntu), that's a GUI way without re-formating it :-) The ONLY thing you need to pay attention is to **unmount** your usb stick before renaming it.

Answer (score 1):

While this may be less optimal for some right after installing Linux. The easiest fix I've found is formatting the USB on Windows.

If it doesn't Appear tap **Start** > Right Click **Computer** > D**isk (or device) Manager** > Carefully delete all the USB partitions then format the new partition.